# HDF5 not writing all the data to the file

Tags: java, hdf5

I am trying out Java examples for HDF5 from their website.

I tried the `bitfield datatype` example https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/java/examples/datatypes/H5Ex_T_Bit.java

I found out that only the 1st row is written. The rest are not written.

I changed the original size of `4x8` array to `5x9`, and only 1st row and a 3 values of 2nd row were written.

```
original array:
0x0000001C, 0x0000001D, 0x0000001E, 0x0000001F, 0x00000020, 0x00000021, 0x00000022, 0x00000023, 0x00000024, 
0x00000025, 0x00000026, 0x00000027, 0x00000028, 0x00000029, 0x0000002A, 0x0000002B, 0x0000002C, 0x0000002D, 
0x0000002E, 0x0000002F, 0x00000030, 0x00000031, 0x00000032, 0x00000033, 0x00000034, 0x00000035, 0x00000036, 
0x00000037, 0x00000038, 0x00000039, 0x0000003A, 0x0000003B, 0x0000003C, 0x0000003D, 0x0000003E, 0x0000003F, 
0x00000040, 0x00000041, 0x00000042, 0x00000043, 0x00000044, 0x00000045, 0x00000046, 0x00000047, 0x00000048, 

Read from HDF5 file
0x0000001C, 0x0000001D, 0x0000001E, 0x0000001F, 0x00000020, 0x00000021, 0x00000022, 0x00000023, 0x00000024, 
0x00000025, 0x00000026, 0x00000027, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 
0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 
0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 
0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000,
```

When I check the file in `HDFView`, the data is filled in incorrect places.

[image]
I am just curious if I missed something when setting up, or missed something when I was reading about it.

Thanks.

I am pretty sure if I spend more time, I would find out the reason. I am just wondering if anyone has the answer on the top of their hat.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Just as I mentioned, I found the issue after spending some time.

I was assuming that the code is bug free since this is from official website. Apparently not.

When they are creating a `dataset`, they are creating for `bitfield` type with keyword `H5T_STD_B8BE`. It means **Standard Bit Datatype which will have 8 bits with Big Endian** notation in this code.

```
dataset_id = H5.H5Dcreate(file_id, DATASETNAME,
                        HDF5Constants.H5T_STD_B8BE, dataspace_id,
                        HDF5Constants.H5P_DEFAULT, HDF5Constants.H5P_DEFAULT, HDF5Constants.H5P_DEFAULT);
```

When they create a sample data to be written to `H5` file, they created an integer array. `int[][] dset_data = new int[DIM0][DIM1];`

Since `int` takes 32 bits, each value is taking 4 spaces in `H5` file.

Simply changing `byte[][] dset_data = new byte[DIM0][DIM1];` will ensure that everything is written correctly.

When reading from the file, also update the pointer array type to `byte`